# Running an exe within a web application

Tags: asp.net, security

I have an asp.net web application and I want to run an executable. The user will enter some details and I will pass those details as a parameter to the exe. The exe will then generate a text file and I will read the contents.

I do trust this executable..but I don't want to compromise security on my web app in order to allow an executable to run.

I read a little in an MS website about creating a sandbox within the web app.

What's the best way to do this? Anyone know?

Currently trying this with no luck..it should create a text file like it does when I run it from a commmand prompt..

```
        Dim process As New Process()
        process.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/app_data/myfolder/myexe.exe")
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/t:1234"
        process.Start()
```

I get a messagebox asking whether I can trust the publisher, but when I click yes I get no text file. Are the arguments being passed correctly?

Thanks,

Comment: This article will help you: [How to: Run Partially Trusted Code in a Sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).